# Тире в пословице

Tags: пунктуация

"Одна голова хорошо, а две (—) лучше" — по-моему, тут просится тире.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просится. Предложение неполное, пропущена часть подлежащего (две головы) плюс соответствующая интонация.

Comment: Однако правило о пунктуации в неполных предложениях гласит, что при отстутствии паузы и интонационного подчеркивания в неполном предложении тире может не ставиться. Так что в данном предложении тире возможно, но не обязательно.

Comment: Здесь есть и пауза, и интонация, не сумлевайтейсь.  
Кстати, не мешало бы и ссылки давать на формулировки. Потому как в реальности праввило гораздо сложнее и есть случаи, когда без тире не обойтись джае если паузы нет. 
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=107